# Adding Headers to Soap Request .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, soap, request-headers

I added a web service reference to my existing visual studio project, I not able to execute any of the service methods as i keep getting "missing headers" error.

Then newly generated proxy class doesn't have method to add headers. Is there a way i can add http header to the request

Answer (score 0):

Override the method GetWebRequest in the proxy class
Then add below code

```
 HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest();
 request.Headers.Add("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");
 return request
```